# Computing a large data set from CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

Lets say I have a csv file with large dataset. This csv file was created from DB i.e. it is essentially a table. what would be the best way to iterate over this csv file and calculate average or sum or do general computation using Python ?

Eg: the csv file has a user id and amount and date associated with it. Now I need to calculate every users monthly spendings. Note that userid is not the primary key and that user might have bought

How should the data be loaded, using pandas or anything other way ?

Comment: I would prefer to connect to the db and query those, but to read the csv file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely try pandas, from what I understand from your problem description,your csv file is formatted like this :

```
user_id amount date
1241    1000   01/Aug/2016
....    ...    ....
```

This should be a good enough solution to start with to calculate the total monthly spendings per user_id

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_filename_path.csv')

df.loc[:,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'date'])
df.loc[:,'month'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'],freq='M')
monthly_spendings = df.groupby(['month','user_id'])['amount'].sum()
```

Comment: Yup thats correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The csv module makes it easy to read from a CSV file.  For example, if the first line of the CSV file contains the column names, and if one of those column names is "user_id", the following lines will display the user_id field from each line:

```
import csv
for rec in csv.DictReader(open("somefile.csv", "rb")):
  print("User ID = {}".format(rec["user_id"]))
```